# Multiple Regression - Calculate Elasticity of demand

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression

If I assume that all of my regression coefficients are statistically significant then how to calculate the point own price elasticity of demand for given price=8, Advertise=10, Income = 50?

```
            Coefficients
Intercept   3611
Price      -237.2
Advertise   32.9
Income      6.37
```

I saw similar questions but did not get a clear approach/answer? Thanks !